# pydantic data types for aws s3 response

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pydantic

I'm trying to build a pydantic model out of the response I get from boto3's `get_object` method. And this is what it looks like

```
{
    'AcceptRanges': 'bytes',
    'Body': <botocore.response.StreamingBody object at 0x116f17490>,
    'ContentLength': 11,
    'ContentType': 'binary/octet-stream',
    'ETag': '"5eb63bbbe01eeed093cb22bb8f5acdc3"',
    'LastModified': datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 1, 18, 9, 22, tzinfo=tzutc()),
    'Metadata': {},
    'ResponseMetadata': {}
}
```

Here's what I came up with and not sure if right, specifically `Body` and `LastModified`.

```
class S3GetObjectResponse(BaseModel):
    AcceptRanges: str
    Body: str
    ContentLength: int
    ContentType: str
    ETag: str
    LastModified: datetime.datetime
    Metadata: dict
    ResponseMetadata: dict
```

Comment: You can add a custom validator executing `pre=True` to parse the `Body` into a JSON? (Or other desired format) – or, you set the dtype = to `botocore.response.StreamingBody`